# R: area under curve of ogive?

Tags: r, integration, cdf

I have an algorithm that uses an x,y plot of sorted y data to produce an ogive.

I then derive the area under the curve to derive %'s.

I'd like to do something similar using kernel density estimation.  I like how the upper/lower bounds are smoothed out using kernel densities (i.e. the min and max will extend slightly beyond my hard coded input).

Either way...  I was wondering if there is a way to treat an ogive as a type of cumulative distribution function and/or use kernel density estimation to derive a cumulative distribution function given y data?

I apologize if this is a confusing question.  I know there is a way to derive a cumulative frequency graph (i.e. ogive).  However, I can't determine how to derive a % given this cumulative frequency graph.

What I don't want is an ecdf.  I know how to do that, and I am not quite trying to capture an ecdf.  But, rather integration of an ogive given two intervals.

Comment: If would be easier to give specific advice if you have some sort of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Despite your protestations to the contrary I think that you are attempting to reinvent the `ecdf` function as an intermediate to your goal. The end result would just be `ecdf(dat)(point2) - ecdf(dat)(point1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you have in mind, but here's a way to calculate the area under the curve for a kernel density estimate (or more generally for any case where you have the y values at equally spaced x-values (though you can, of course, generalize to variable x intervals as well)):

```
library(zoo)

# Kernel density estimate
# Set n to higher value to get a finer grid
set.seed(67839)
dens = density(c(rnorm(500,5,2),rnorm(200,20,3)), n=2^5)

# How to extract the x and y values of the density estimate
#dens$y
#dens$x

# x interval
dx = median(diff(dens$x))

# mean height for each pair of y values
h = rollmean(dens$y, 2)

# Area under curve
sum(h*dx)  # 1.000943

# Cumulative area
# cumsum(h*dx)

# Plot density, showing points at which density is calculated 
plot(dens)
abline(v=dens$x, col="#FF000060", lty="11")
```

[image]

```
# Plot cumulative area under curve, showing mid-point of each x-interval
plot(dens$x[-length(dens$x)] + 0.5*dx, cumsum(h*dx), type="l")
abline(v=dens$x[-length(dens$x)] + 0.5*dx, col="#FF000060", lty="11")
```

[image]

**UPDATE to include `ecdf` function**

To address your comments, look at the two plots below. The first is the empirical cumulative distribution function (ECDF) of the mixture of normal distributions that I used above. Note that the plot of this data looks the same below as it does above. The second is a plot of the ECDF of a plain vanilla normal distribution, mean=0, sd=1.

```
set.seed(67839)
x = c(rnorm(500,5,2),rnorm(200,20,3))
plot(ecdf(x), do.points=FALSE)

plot(ecdf(rnorm(1000)))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you.  Is there also a way to do the this with the density plot itself?  I'm not sure if I need that, but figured I'd ask.

Comment: As @42- mentioned, it sounds like you want a plot of the cumulative density: `plot(ecdf(rnorm(1000)))`.

Comment: but ecdf always results in a 45 degree angle when done cumulative.  That never looks like a cdf, in your picture here it looks like a (Albeit weird) cdf.  And again, a ecdf won't extend the edges as is done with a density plot (which uses kernel density estimation)

Comment: That's the shape of the ecdf of a normal distribution. The plot does go to the edges. `rnorm(1000)` will give values ranging (very roughly) from about -3.5 to 3.5. If you plot the mixture of normals I used in my answer, then you get the shape in my second plot. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That ecdf doesn't look like a 45 degree line at all!

Comment: okay, after figuring out how to install zoo, I was able to replicate most of the setup. I imagine I'm supposed to divide something by sum(h*dx) but not sure how to derive the area under the curve for a specific x value.

Comment: I think I get it.  the second graph is the area under the curve of the 1st graph.  Now I want to do the area under the curve of an ecdf.